# Vimium browsing with textfields and different scrollable elements

Tags: macos, google-chrome, vim

I'm using vimium:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb

It's a way to browse / navigate with a keyboard.

I generally love it but I don't know how to navigate in/out of textfields or different scrollable elements.

For example if I have a textfield selected how do I return focus to the body?

If I want to focus on a specific element on the page so I can scroll it how do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit `?` to show a list of bindings. And `<Esc>` to get out of a textfield.

Comment: What about the scrollable element?

Comment: What do you mean by scrollable element? Aside from `gf` to cycle frames, I don't believe vimium supports any selection of sub scrolling areas.

Comment: Right, not a frame just an element with overflow: scroll; There's no way to select it? Also no way to click on buttons that activate via javascript instead of anchors?

Comment: Do you use `f`?

Comment: Yes of course, can't navigate without it.

Comment: Well, if you can't jump to a specific element with `f`, `F` or `gi`, the answer is probably "no". Did you consider using [Vimium's issue tracker](https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues)?

Comment: this answer is not that helpful since the user posting didn't check the help first if it had the answer.

Comment: I have the same issue, so to clarify, as an example, Youtube's homepage has a sidebar to the left which is scrollable. I've actually managed to put focus on the sidebar so I'm able to scroll the sidebar and not the main content. However, after setting the focus inside the sidebar, I'm unable to shift focus back into the main content area, so now I'm only able to scroll the sidebar.

Another example, open the inbox here on stack. How would one scroll the popup?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a textfield, then you can focus out of it, and back into vim mode using `Esc`. If you need to move to a different frame on the webpage you can use `gf`. This is useful if there are multiple scrollbars on the page. However, if you need to first move out of the textfield, you need to use `Esc`.

You can view additional info about this by pressing the `?` key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).